# How to create a windows form application which enables users to work offline?

Tags: database, synchronization, local, offline

I want to create a windows form application which should be able to do Add/Edit/Delete records on server database when there is connectivity but if there are any connectivity issues the user should still be able to work offline and then sync it back to server when the connection is restored.

I read about Microsoft Sync Framework and Local Database Cache but I don't find Local Database Cache in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Local Database Cache was taken out in VS 2012.

You can however use SQL Server Compact Toolbox to something similar, see: [SQL SERVER COMPACT TOOLBOX SYNC FRAMEWORK SUPPORT](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/sql-server-compact-toolbox-sync-framework-support/)

there's no stopping you handcoding the sync using Sync Fx as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your own data set which can be updated offline. The only thing is just write the data set to an XML file and when ever the user changes, update the dataset and rewrite the corresponding data set XML using the ds.writexml and ds.writexmlschema methods.